# Can I use "imply" as a synonym for "indicate" in this sentence?

Tags: synonyms

Can I use **imply** as a synonym for **indicate** in this sentence or is there a more suitable word?

> The status attribute with the value of 201 is a signal sent from the service provider to the client to **indicate** a successful updating of the usere's record in the bus table.

Answer (score 1):

**Imply** and **indicate** have different meanings:

**indicate** means that the result is **straightforwardly** or **directly** determined
**imply** means that the result is **indirectly** determined.

**Indicate** has a higher exactness than **imply**.

> A return code of 201 **indicates** the update was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Imply and indicate are synonyms in the sense that both can be used to mean suggest or express indirectly.

I think you can replace indicate with suggest or imply in the sentence presented.